# moving from sharer.php to the new like button

Tags: facebook

I am trying to move from old facebook `sharer.php` to the new facebook like button.

I have a page with a list of items where the user can click on the ones they like, so it's a *single* page website. Now, I have read that I need to use the following meta in my header to give facebook the information about what image or item they are liking: `<meta property="og:image" content="image.jpg">` Problem with this is pretty obvious:

There are many items in a single page and obviously a single meta in the header won't do. Is there anyway to let graph api know which item in particular they are liking? With the sharer.php tool, I would have done something like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php
  ?s=100
  &p%5Btitle%5D=Title+here.
  &p%5Bsummary%5D=Description+goes+here
  &p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fimage.jpg
  &p%5Burl%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“Is there anyway to let graph api know which item in particular they are liking?”_ – no, likes happen on the basis of the URL, not on “items”. You have to have a separate URL for each item you want to be like-able. If you want to keep your single page, set up URLs for the items that deliver the relevant info to Facebook, and redirect actual users to the relevant section on your single page.

Comment: this can never work with single page apps that use # to delimit pages.

Comment: I just _told you_ how it works: Set up new separate URLs, one for each item – no hashes, just “simple” URLs that provide the necessary info for one item each. Those URLs are the ones to be liked, and the Facebook scraper will get its info from those. And when a _normal user_ visits those URLs (from the Facebook news feed where he finds them linked to), they just redirect him to the appropriate section on your single page app.