# Facebook - multiple like buttons with one host page (GWT)

Tags: javascript, facebook, gwt, facebook-like, meta-tags

I want to add facebook like buttons to different pages and use different titles, descriptions and images.

The problem now is: Facebook uses meta tags from the header to determine this values, e.g.: . I use GWT and therefore I only have one host page (e.g. index.html) and different content is rendered in this page:
"www.myurl.com#blogpost:1" would load the blogpost with id "1". Therefore every blogpost would have the same title, description, image. I could change the metatags with javascript according to which blogpost is requested. But I guess javascript is not executed by the facebook parser. Is there a way to realize different like buttons with only one host page?

Comment: I outlined the only way this can work in the comments on a question here two days ago, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047068/moving-from-sharer-php-to-the-new-like-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now generate a special link for facebook. So if my GWT URL looks like "www.myurl.com#blogpost:1", I will generate the URL "www.myurl.com/fb/blogpost/1". Now I check in a Servlet Filter for URLs starting with "fb". If I find a Request with a URL like that, I just write out the Meta tags and a java script forward to my actual page: "www.myurl.com#blogpost:1". The facebook crawler just sees the meta tags and doesn't use the javascript forward.

Normal Users on the other hand are forwarded to the regular page. This works pretty good for me. Thanks CBroe for the hint.

Comment: What do you mean by " I just write out the Meta tags and a java script forward to my actual page"? Could you please provide some sample code for that?